# Does Krishna really love any one?

Tags: krishna, gods, bhagavad-gita

In one of the shlokas of Bhagavath Geetha, Krishna says "**I neither love nor hate any one**".

The shloka I am referring to is [BG 4.11](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/11):

> ye yathā māṁ prapadyante tāṁs tathaiva bhajāmy aham mama
>   vartmānuvartante manuṣyāḥ pārtha sarvaśaḥ

But why do people say that God has infinite love towards all?

Did I misunderstand the shloka?

Comment: That verse doesn't say anything about loving or hating.  It just says "As all surrender unto Me, I reward them accordingly. Everyone follows My path in all respects, O son of Pṛthā." http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/11 Perhaps you're thinking of a different verse?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9X3R_y1Y94#t=993

Then possibly it may be a wrong interpretation in my mother tongue Telugu. A Telugu person may clarify it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't speak Telegu.  But perhaps you intend to refer to this verse:  http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/29 "I envy no one, nor am I partial to anyone. I am equal to all. But whoever renders service unto Me in devotion is a friend, is in Me, and I am also a friend to him."

Comment: Real love is love which is without attachment. When Krishna says he neither favors anyone, nor is envy of anyone, that is what he means. His love is not limited, it is not bounded, or attached. He is not blinded by attached love, the way Dritarashtra was to his son Duryodhana. Krishna has true love, detached love for everyone.

Comment: I added a link in the question. OP is talking about [BG 4.11](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/11). I think the speaker in the video translates part of the shloka or its meaning incorrectly.

Comment: It means he is totally and utterly unbiased. God only ever has anugraham never agraham. To explain, Graham means grasping, holding. Anu means following. Therefore anugraham means that which follows (the devotee's) act of graham (of paramatma). Agraham means withholding. Krishna never withholds. He doles out the fruits of our devotion according to its merit. In nirguna form parabrahma has no raga or dwesha. In saguna form, he does have daya. Remember how he is totally devoted to arjuna and the gopis. In

Comment: what it means is that he does not grant moksha just because someone did lot of tapas, or donation etc. and that he does not deny moksha just because someone did not do above. in other words, his grace does not have condition. but does that mean anyone can get it? nope. but isn't that contradicting ? nope. think of rain and rain-water-harvesting. suppose you dig a big hole, then when rain falls, you can catch & store it. does it mean rain fell BECAUSE you dug a hole ? No. Does it mean you need not dig a hole ? No. Dig a hole, be patient, wait for his grace. Don't think it rained because of u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to following Bhagavad Geeta shlokha. The speaker in the [YouTube video you mention](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9X3R_y1Y94#t=993) has got some of the translation (*I neither love nor hate any one*) wrong. The translation by [A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/preface) is below.

> [Bg 4.11](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/11)
>
> ye yathā māṁ prapadyante tāṁs tathaiva bhajāmyaham mama
> vartmānuvartante manuṣyāḥ pārtha sarvaśaḥ
>
> Word for word: 
> ye — all
> who; yathā — as; mām — unto Me; prapadyante — surrender; tān — them;
> tathā — so; eva — certainly; bhajāmi — reward; aham — I; mama — My;
> vartma — path; anuvartante — follow; manuṣyāḥ — all men; pārtha — O
> son of Pṛthā; sarvaśaḥ — in all respects.
>
> Translation: 
> **As all surrender unto Me, I reward them accordingly. Everyone follows My path in all respects, O son of Pṛthā.**

Comment: I don't speak Telegu, but I highly doubt that the speaker mistranslated 4.11 as "I neither love nor hate anyone".  There's absolutely nothing in the Sanskrit that would lead anyone to that meaning.   I think the speaker just accidentally gave the Sanskrit verse 4.11 when he intended to give the Sanskit verse 9.29, and then he proceeded to give the meaning of 9.29.  In any case, I think a good answer to the question should address 9.29 and how it can be reconciled with the idea that Vishnu loves everyone.

Comment: The Telugu speaker ([Ghantasala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghantasala_(singer)#Private_recordings_and_Bhagavad_Gita)) in the video does translate the **I reward them accordingly** part of [Bg 4.11](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/11) correctly, it's the latter part that he interprets differently. So I highly doubt that he's referring to [9.29](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/29). BTW, among the Telugu community, the particular video/audio is a popular introduction to Bhagavad Geeta as you can tell from the YouTube view count.

Answer (score 5):

You can read Bhagavad Gita in Telugu [here.](http://www.telugubhakti.com/telugupages/Gita/Gita.html)
The translation in Telugu is same as the translation in English.
Here is the meaning of verse 4.11 in Telugu:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am answering only from Gita. I think you were talking actually of this sloka :

> समोऽहं सर्वभूतेषु न मे द्वेष्योऽस्ति न प्रियः।
>
> ये भजन्ति तु मां भक्त्या मयि ते तेषु चाप्यहम्।।9.29।।
>
> I am impartial towards all beings; **to Me there is none detastable or none dear.** But those who worship Me with devotion, they exist in Me, and I too exist in them.

But in other places of the Gita, Sri Krishna does express His love to His devotess, to the Jnanis, to the yogis and to Arjuna:

> यो मां पश्यति सर्वत्र सर्वं च मयि पश्यति।
>
> तस्याहं न प्रणश्यामि स च मे न प्रणश्यति।।6.30।।
>
> One who sees Me in everything, and sees all things in Me-I do not out of his vision, and **he also is not lost to My vision.**
>
> तेषां ज्ञानी नित्ययुक्त एकभक्ितर्विशिष्यते।
>
> प्रियो हि ज्ञानिनोऽत्यर्थमहं स च मम प्रियः।।7.17।।
>
> Of them, the man of Knowledge, endowed with constant steadfastness and one-pointed devotion, excels. For I am very much dear to the man of Knowledge, and **he too is dear to Me.**
>
> अनपेक्षः शुचिर्दक्ष उदासीनो गतव्यथः।
>
> सर्वारम्भपरित्यागी यो मद्भक्तः स मे प्रियः।।12.16।।
>
> He who has no desires, who is pure, who is dextrous, who is impartial, who is free from fear, who has renounced every undertaking-he who is (**such) a devotee of Mine is dear to Me.**
>
> यो न हृष्यति न द्वेष्टि न शोचति न काङ्क्षति।
>
> शुभाशुभपरित्यागी भक्ितमान्यः स मे प्रियः।।12.17।।
>
> He who does not rejoice, does not fret, does not lament, does not hanker; who gives up good and bad, who is filled with devotion-**he is dear to Me.**
>
> समः शत्रौ च मित्रे च तथा मानापमानयोः।
>
> शीतोष्णसुखदुःखेषु समः सङ्गविवर्जितः।।12.18।।
>
> He who is the same towards friend and foe, and so also in honour and dishonour; who is the same under cold, heat, happiness and sorrow, who is free from attachment to everything.
>
> तुल्यनिन्दास्तुतिर्मौनी सन्तुष्टो येनकेनचित्।
>
> अनिकेतः स्थिरमतिर्भक्ितमान्मे प्रियो नरः।।12.19।।
>
> **The person to whom denunciation and praise are the same, who is silent, content with anything, homeless, steady-minded, and full of devotion is dear to Me.**
>
> ये तु धर्म्यामृतमिदं यथोक्तं पर्युपासते।
>
> श्रद्दधाना मत्परमा भक्तास्तेऽतीव मे प्रियाः।।12.20।।
>
> But [Tu (but) is used to distinguish those who have attained the highest Goal from the aspirants.-Tr.] those devotees who accept Me as the supreme Goal, and with faith seek for this ambrosia [M.S.'s reading is dharmamrtam-nectar in the form of virtue. Virtue is called nectar because it leads to Immortality, or because it is sweet like nectar.] which is indistinguishable from the virtues as stated above, **they are very dear to Me.**
>
> सर्वगुह्यतमं भूयः श्रृणु मे परमं वचः।
>
> इष्टोऽसि मे दृढमिति ततो वक्ष्यामि ते हितम्।।18.64।।
>
> Listen again to My highest utterance which is the profoundest of all. **Since you are ever dear to Me, therefore I shall speak what is beneficial to you.**
>
> मन्मना भव मद्भक्तो मद्याजी मां नमस्कुरु।
>
> मामेवैष्यसि सत्यं ते प्रतिजाने प्रियोऽसि मे।।18.65।।
>
> 18.65 Have your mind fixed on Me, be My devotee, be a sacrificer to Me and bow down to Me. (Thus) you will come to Me alone. (This) truth do I pormise to you. (For) **you are dear to Me.**

And lastly I quote the following verses :

> पिताऽहमस्य जगतो माता धाता पितामहः।
>
> वेद्यं पवित्रमोंकार ऋक् साम यजुरेव च।।9.17।।
>
> गतिर्भर्ता प्रभुः साक्षी निवासः शरणं सुहृत्।
>
> प्रभवः प्रलयः स्थानं निधानं बीजमव्ययम्।।9.18।।
>
> **Of this world I am the** **father**, **mother**, ordainer, (and the), **grand-father**. I am the knowable, the sancitifier, the syllable Om as also Rk, Sama and Yajus.Yajus.
>
> (I am) the fruit of actions, the nourisher, the Lord, witness, abode, refuge, **friend**, origin, end, foundation, store and the imperishable seed.

**Being the Father, Mother, Grand-Fathernand the Friend of the Universe, He must have infinite love and compassion for all.**